# Hints to debug ghostscript missing font error

Tags: fonts, ghostscript

For some reason, I get an invalid font error.  Output of `epstopdf AppStartup.eps --debug` indicates an invalid font, but I am really not sure what font is missing.  This is being invoked by pdflatex called from latexmk and the eps file was produced by the diagram drawing program 'dia,' version 0.97.3, BTW.

```
* kpsewhich command: kpsewhich
* Input filename: AppStartup.eps
* Output filename: AppStartup.pdf
* BoundingBox comment: %%BoundingBox:
* Ghostscript command: gs
* Compression: on
* Embedding: on
* Grayscale: off
* PDFSettings: prepress
* Resolution: [use gs default]
* Rotation: None
* Ghostscript pipe: gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=AppStartup.pdf -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dAutoRotatePages#/None - -c quit
* Binary junk at start of file: 0 byte(s)
* Scanning header for BoundingBox
* Old BoundingBox: 0 0 1156 1679
* New BoundingBox: 0 0 1156 1679
* Offset: 0 0
GPL Ghostscript 9.22 (2017-10-04)
Copyright (C) 2017 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Regular.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusRoman-Regular.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Regular.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusRoman-Regular.
Querying operating system for font files...
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Regular.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusRoman-Regular.
Loading NimbusRoman-Regular font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-Regular.t1... 5123292 3661824 5990816 4566382 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Italic.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusRoman-Italic.
Loading NimbusRoman-Italic font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-Italic.t1... 5270204 3887840 5990816 4574321 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Bold.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusRoman-Bold.
Loading NimbusRoman-Bold font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-Bold.t1... 5497916 4116300 6011016 4585409 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-BoldItalic.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusRoman-BoldItalic.
Loading NimbusRoman-BoldItalic font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-BoldItalic.t1... 5725628 4352309 6011016 4592886 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/AvantGarde-Gothic.
Can't find (or can't open) font file AvantGarde-Gothic.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Substituting font AvantGarde-Book for AvantGarde-Gothic.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/URWGothic-Book.
Can't find (or can't open) font file URWGothic-Book.
Loading URWGothic-Book font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWGothic-Book.t1... 5933140 4545268 6031216 4607216 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/URWGothic-BookOblique.
Can't find (or can't open) font file URWGothic-BookOblique.
Loading URWGothic-BookOblique font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWGothic-BookOblique.t1... 6120452 4741896 6031216 4614816 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/URWGothic-Demi.
Can't find (or can't open) font file URWGothic-Demi.
Loading URWGothic-Demi font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWGothic-Demi.t1... 6327964 4937570 6051416 4625906 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/URWGothic-DemiOblique.
Can't find (or can't open) font file URWGothic-DemiOblique.
Loading URWGothic-DemiOblique font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWGothic-DemiOblique.t1... 6515276 5131100 6051416 4633378 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/URWBookman-Light.
Can't find (or can't open) font file URWBookman-Light.
Loading URWBookman-Light font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWBookman-Light.t1... 6763188 5367602 6071616 4644372 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/URWBookman-LightItalic.
Can't find (or can't open) font file URWBookman-LightItalic.
Loading URWBookman-LightItalic font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWBookman-LightItalic.t1... 7011100 5609319 6071616 4652209 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/URWBookman-Demi.
Can't find (or can't open) font file URWBookman-Demi.
Loading URWBookman-Demi font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWBookman-Demi.t1... 7238812 5841936 6091816 4663199 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/URWBookman-DemiItalic.
Can't find (or can't open) font file URWBookman-DemiItalic.
Loading URWBookman-DemiItalic font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWBookman-DemiItalic.t1... 7486724 6083101 6091816 4670672 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusMonoPS-Regular.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusMonoPS-Regular.
Loading NimbusMonoPS-Regular font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-Regular.t1... 7714436 6318898 6112016 4681684 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusMonoPS-Italic.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusMonoPS-Italic.
Loading NimbusMonoPS-Italic font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-Italic.t1... 7962348 6560386 6112016 4689157 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusMonoPS-Bold.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusMonoPS-Bold.
Loading NimbusMonoPS-Bold font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-Bold.t1... 8230460 6818620 6132216 4700773 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusMonoPS-BoldItalic.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusMonoPS-BoldItalic.
Loading NimbusMonoPS-BoldItalic font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-BoldItalic.t1... 8478372 7071222 6132216 4708256 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusSans-Regular.
Loading NimbusSans-Regular font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSans-Regular.t1... 8685884 7267491 6152416 4719250 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Italic.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusSans-Italic.
Loading NimbusSans-Italic font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSans-Italic.t1... 8873196 7465695 6152416 4726713 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusSans-Bold.
Loading NimbusSans-Bold font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSans-Bold.t1... 9080708 7665818 6172616 4737703 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-BoldItalic.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusSans-BoldItalic.
Loading NimbusSans-BoldItalic font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSans-BoldItalic.t1... 9288220 7869668 6172616 4745176 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusSansNarrow-Regular.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusSansNarrow-Regular.
Loading NimbusSansNarrow-Regular font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-Regular.t1... 9495732 8066191 6192816 4756196 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusSansNarrow-Oblique.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusSansNarrow-Oblique.
Loading NimbusSansNarrow-Oblique font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-Oblique.t1... 9683044 8261994 6192816 4763792 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusSansNarrow-Bold.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusSansNarrow-Bold.
Loading NimbusSansNarrow-Bold font from /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-Bold.t1... 9890556 8460468 6213016 4774808 2 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusSansNarrow-BdOblique.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusSansNarrow-BdOblique.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.22/Resource/Font/NimbusSansNarrow-BdOblique.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusSansNarrow-BdOblique.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Unable to substitute for font.
Error: /invalidfont in /findfont
Operand stack:
   Helvetica-Narrow-BoldOblique-latin1   Helvetica-Narrow-BoldOblique
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1999   1   3   %oparray_pop   1998   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1982   1   3   %oparray_pop   1868   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1951   2   3   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:987/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:114/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Not a directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.22: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
epstopdf ($Id: epstopdf.pl 41577 2016-06-30 16:38:01Z karl $) 2.26
!!! Error: Writing to gs failed, error code 1
```

The last font mentioned is NimbusSansNarrow-BdOblique, which is present alongside other fonts reported as loaded:

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-BdOblique.*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 114642 Sep 22 04:19 /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-BdOblique.afm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 109815 Sep 22 04:19 /usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-BdOblique.t1
```

Thus, I'm not sure where the problem is or how to go about correcting it.

Ghostscript version is 9.22 (2017-10-04) distributed with Fedora 27.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly Ghostscript bug #698784:

https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=698784

As reported by the Fedora package maintainer.

Fixed in this commit :
http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commit;h=efc24229b0ba4b2f6a39fe89a4c9c576dbe7e124